# declare: not found error in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, ubuntu, centos, scripting, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline which has a step running a `sh` script. Something like this, but with more commands in between which are not relevant:

```
steps {
            echo 'Running build with all parameters'
                sh '''
                    #!/bin/bash

                    declare -A tests
```

... etc

When I run it on a Jenkins node with CentOS, everything is fine, pipeline runs successfully with all the steps/commands. But when I run the same pipeline on a Jenkins node with Ubuntu, I get this error:

```
+ declare -A tests
/opt/jenkins-slave/workdir/workspace/Metaweb@tmp/durable-9a389b8a/script.sh: 14: declare: not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the script is running with `bash` and not with `sh`? Can Jenkins take `bash` instead of `sh` there?

Comment: `sh` should execute the block with whatever shell is configured.  What is configured under "Shell" on the global configuration?

Comment: i'm not sure, since i don't have admin rights on Jenkins, but i thought it will execute with bash since i'm specifying `#!/bin/bash` inside my script. Also, what would be the explanation of why it's working on CentOS and not on Ubuntu nodes? We have only 1 Jenkins which has both Ubuntu and CentOS node executors.

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have currently written your script, there is a very subtle newline before the shebang.  To make the newlines explicit:

```
sh '''\n
  #!/bin/bash\n
\n
  declare -A tests\n
```

For the shebang to be correctly interpreted, it needs to be on the very first line of the script, so you need to get rid of the leading newline; i.e.:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash

  declare -A tests
```